# can I calculate a new related annual statistic from annual and lifetime data?

Tags: covariance

If I know that 45% of the population will suffer from a particular strain of influenza over their lifetime (and 55% never will) and I also know that in any one year 20% of the population have this strain of influenza, can I infer for any year the percentage of the population that will get that strain of influenza for the first time?